"Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar" breaks drag-and-drop to open new tab on Chrome/macOS
Enabling the experimental flag "Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar" on macOS unfortunately breaks drag-and-drop to search or open link in a new tab. The feature still works on windowed mode, but maximizing the Chrome window breaks it. Any fixes that are not workarounds?
Workarounds that I'm not interested in:

I know I can "zoom" the window instead of maximizing it, but that takes up space at the top and bottom of the screen and is distracting
I also know I can disable "Immersive Fullscreen Toolbar", but then hovering over the menu bar will show the window title bar, which covers the tab bar

